# Reloading UITableView while downloading images via afnetworking

Tags: uitableview, uiimage, afnetworking

in my cellForRowAtIndexPath method I've got some code to download images asynchronously via UIImageView+AFNetworking category
But as far I understand cellForRowAtIndexPath method is called every time I scroll the table to the cell, and every time the image download is started. Can I cache the images or the cells or someting like that?

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    //some code here
    [imageView setImageWithURL: myURL placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"]];
    //some other code here
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: not [imageView setImageWithURL: myURL placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"]];

Comment: but [cell.imageView setImageWithURL: myURL placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"]];

Comment: You can use the `edit` link to make corrections to your posted code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`UIImageView+AFNetworking` will automatically cache your images using `AFImageCache` (an `NSCache` subclass) so they won't need to download twice.

When a cell scrolls back into view it will use the cached image instead of making a network call, as long as the URL is the same.

It would probably be useful for you to skim through the implementation source of this category if you will be using it regularly.  The [source code can be found here](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/AFNetworking/UIImageView+AFNetworking.m).